# Upgraded to Sitecore 6.6, Lucene 2.9.4, and dynamic fields stopped working

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6, lucene

We had a Sitecore 6.5 installation that worked with dynamic fields and Sitecore.SharedSource.Search, using Lucene.NET 2.3.1.3 . However, after upgrading to Sitecore 6.6 and Lucene.NET 2.9.4 , all search indexing and other features work except for dynamic fields, using the same configuration for the dynamic fields. Rebuilding indexes using the Advanced Database Crawler, IndexViewer, etc. does nothing. What could be responsible for this?

Attempting to debug verifies that the dynamic fields are created, but that they for some reason are not successfully added to the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the scSearchContrib codebase (a reworked version of the Sitecore.SharedSource.Search codebase) eventually solved the problem, although it was far from a simple drop-in replacement.